# Jquery Issue when getting a checked value of a check box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to get a value of a check box using JQuery. When I try out the code below it always returned 'false' as the check box result, even when I check the check box.

```
var result = $("#checkkBoxId").is(':checked');
```

Then I tried out the other way, as follows. But it always returned 'undefined' as the result.

```
var result = $("#checkkBoxId").attr('checked');
```

Any idea why these code parts are failing to work correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the checkbox properly?

Comment: I agree with Caleb, looks to me like you might not be getting the element. See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JXGhp/

Comment: Caleb Doucet and FlabbyRabbit - thank you very much for your quick responses. I'm quite sure that I'm getting the checkbox element correctly, because I checked it via the visual studio immediate window and quick watch. But when I checked the outcome of     $("#checkkBoxId").attr('checked');
it says that the attr is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be pretty confident that the problem is that the element your selector matches does not exist or is not a checkbox. Is the double 'k' in your selector a typo?

As an aside, for checking the checkedness of a single checkbox, I strongly urge you to skip jQuery and go directly for the DOM boolean `checked` property, which could not possibly be simpler to use or more reliable.

SO regular Andy E has a [relevant blog post about this kind of thing](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/utilizing-the-awesome-power-of-jquery-to-access-properties-of-an-element).

```
var result = $("#checkkBoxId")[0].checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like more of an issue of do you have the right variable name?  User developer tools or firebug to ensure you have the right ID name.  If you do not have it set to client mode of static, it gets rendered with a different ID name through the browser.

Share the code of the check box?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have used firebug and the visual studio immediate window and quick watch to make sure whether I get the checkbox element correctly. And I was able to make sure that the element is returned correctly when I type    $("#checkkBoxId") in the immediate window. But when I checked the outcome of $("#checkkBoxId").attr('checked'); it says that the attr is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the ID of the element is wrong.
Probably there is a typo: check**k**BoxId in the ID of the checkbox.